# Regex to match a list

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text: `some unknown random stuff here: (ben, tim, sam toben, suzei)`

I need to use **regex only** to pull out each of the items from the (unknown sized) comma separated list: `ben`, `tim`, `sam toben`, `suzei` into the matched groups. Leading/trailing whitespace doesn't matter.

I tried the following: `(?:\(([^,]+))` but it will only pull out `ben` as a group.

Any ideas?

Comment: What language. You will probably need to use something more than just plain regex for this. E.g. a split method or something like that...

Comment: @Jan - I forgot there were language specific implementations, I shall tag - thank you.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - I need to use regex only sadly otherwise I could use string splitting.

Comment: Java regex cannot have dynamic number of matching groups in a single expression. What you're asking is impossible. You can do it with a `find()` loop, though. Would that be ok? Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/MDAMk9/1)?

Comment: There is no such thing as "regex only" for a concrete problem like this. You must have some regex implementation in mind here.

Comment: Actually, [Jan's deleted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39836677/3832970) shows the closest way - [`(?:\(|\G(?!\A)[, ]*)(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/fvQWAl/2). There is no other way in Java: there is no `\K` operator support in Java regex.

Comment: do you really want the groups, or do you just want the values, for example as an array?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't something you can do in the way you want with regexes *only*. It is, however, possible to do it using regexes and `String.split()`.

Something like this:

```
String[] getList(String text) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+\\((.+)\\)"); // Note the doubled backslashes
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
        return m.group(1).split(",");
    } else {
        return new String[0];
    }
}
```

[Demo of the regex on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KAZmGm/1)

What this does is grab the contents of the brackets, then split those contents into an array on the comma character.

Comment: You are splitting the matched text with single quote('), but you need to split it with comma(,). If not it will return the string without splitting.